# Add a class to all sibling element if one of the element gets that same class when clicked?

Tags: javascript, class, dom-events, element, siblings

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".img_items");

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("click", () => {
    image.classList.add("select");
  });
});
```

```css
.img_items::after{
  content: ' ' attr(class)
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="img_items ">1</div>
  <div class="img_items ">2</div>
  <div class="img_items">3</div>
  <div class="img_items">4</div>
</div>
```

I tried adding the class to the variable (images) itself on item click event but it didn't add the class to the sibling items.

```
images.classList.add("select")
```

How do we achieve this?

Comment: Made you a snippet.

Comment: Why not add the class on the parent instead?

Comment: `images` isn't an element, it's a list of elements. You need to loop over it to add a class to each element, just like you do when adding the event listeners.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That won't work here, since the style uses `attr(class)`, which will only get the class of the item, not the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class to each element in a loop, just like adding the event listener.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".img_items");

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("click", () => {
    images.forEach(image => image.classList.add("select"));
  });
});
```

```css
.img_items::after {
  content: ' ' attr(class)
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="img_items ">1</div>
  <div class="img_items ">2</div>
  <div class="img_items">3</div>
  <div class="img_items">4</div>
</div>
```

If you only want to do it for the siblings in the same `.img_container`, you can use DOM navigation to first select them and loop over them, rather than looping over all `images`.

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".img_items");

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let siblings = image.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".img_items");
    siblings.forEach(image => image.classList.add("select"));
  });
});
```

```css
.img_items::after {
  content: ' ' attr(class)
}
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="img_items ">1</div>
  <div class="img_items ">2</div>
  <div class="img_items">3</div>
  <div class="img_items">4</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="img_items ">5</div>
  <div class="img_items ">6</div>
  <div class="img_items">7</div>
  <div class="img_items">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man... Dom navigation technique was really helpful.. was scratching my head for ways to select  sibling elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to explain why you aren't getting the expected behavior:

What your code is doing is looping over all elements that have the `img_items` class and attaching a `click` `eventListener` to each one.

That event listener takes the selected image and adds the class `select` to **that image only**.

essentially, your code is equivalent to the following:

```
images[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
    image[0].classList.add("select");
});

images[1].addEventListener("click", () => {
    image[1].classList.add("select");
});

images[2].addEventListener("click", () => {
    image[2].classList.add("select");
});

images[3].addEventListener("click", () => {
    image[3].classList.add("select");
});
```

So you are only changing the `classlist` of the selected element.

Thus, instead, you need to loop through the elements again inside the `eventListener` like so:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".img_items");

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.addEventListener("click", () => {
    images.forEach((image) => {
      image.classList.add("select");
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="img_container">
  <div class="img_items ">img1</div>
  <div class="img_items ">img2</div>
  <div class="img_items">img3</div>
  <div class="img_items">img4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explaination and answer.